# C++ remove certain character from string

Tags: c++

I am in the process of making an Rcon tool for call of duty Modern Warfare 2.
When I get the server information it uses colours with the colour codes ^1 = red ^2 = green and so on, basically what I want to do is remove the ^'Number' from the string^ can anyone tell me how to remove these characters from system string? 
i'd like something simple like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    if(char=="^" + i)
    {
        string ^servernamme -= char;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not only that this code isn't valid c++, what do you think `string ^servernamme -= char;` should do??

Comment: I know that code wouldn't work I am used to coding GSC (call of duty files) I mean something like string ^servername remove(char); something like that

Comment: Check the [`remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) algorithm.

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the '^' character followed by any decimal digit from a string?

Comment: That's using std::string I just want to know if there's a function to remove from system::string^ ?

Comment: @Logicrat not a decimal basically i want to remove "^1" "^2" all the way to "^9"

Comment: @user3740948 Any of "0123456789" is what I meant by "decimal digit."

Comment: Is the text _literally_ a circumflex ^ followed by one decimal digit 0..9, or are you actually looking at an _escape code_ for 0x00, 0x01, etc.?

Comment: @Logicrat sorry i misunderstood the first time, yes that is correct what you said. Is there a way to do this without using std::string and keeping it short and sweet using string^ ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `std::string`'s methods, something like:

```
size_t start = 0;
for (size_t pos = str.find('^', start); pos != std:npos; pos = str.find('^', start))
    if (str.find_first_of("0123456789", pos) == pos + 1)
        str.erase(pos, 2);
    else
        start = pos + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's allways the last 2 characters you wish to remove, you can just use:

`string result = theString.substr(0, theString.size()-1);`

Comment: The characters are placed randomly with in the string to create colours for different words and letters, there are no specific places that the characters will be placed, each different server name will have them placed in a different place. I want it to read the server name but exclude the colour codes("^1" ect)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str.resize(std::distance(str.begin(), std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '^')));
```

That is, move the `'^'`s to the end and resize to trim them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this without using std::string, then I would assume you have theString declared as char[] or char*.

Then you could do something like this:

```
 for(int i = 0; strlen(theString) > i; ++i)
 {
   if (theString[i] == '^' && isdigit(theString[i+1]))
   {
     strcpy(theString+i, theString+i+2);
     --i; // decrement loop index so we won't miss any bytes
   }
 }
```

I hope that's what you're looking for.

Comment: `isdigit()` is defined in `<ctype.h>`